# How do I clear the input field and bind the return key to a button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a very simple app to scrub lists of numbers for easy copying to my database.  I've got everything working except for two simple user functions.

How can I have the input field automatically clear after the button is clicked?

How do I bind the enter key to the button in the app?

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x400")
root.title(" Convert Numbers ")
 
def Take_input(event=None):
    INPUT = inputtxt.get("1.0", "end-1c")

    numbers = INPUT.replace(") ", "").replace("(", "").replace("-", "")

    # Convert the numbers to strings.
    numbers = numbers.split()

    # Join the numbers with commas.
    converted_numbers = ", ".join(numbers)

    num_list = converted_numbers.split(", ")
    num_set = set(num_list)
    output = ', '.join(num_set)    

    Output.delete('1.0', END)
    Output.insert(END, output)
    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(output)
    # inputtxt.delete()

     
l = Label(text = "Paste from FastPeople.com Here:")
inputtxt = Text(root, height = 10,
                width = 25,
                bg = "light yellow")
 
Output = Text(root, height = 10,
              width = 25,
              bg = "light cyan")
 
Display = Button(root, height = 2,
                 width = 20,
                 text ="Click here to convert.\n Copy from below.",
                 command = lambda:Take_input())

# Display.bind('<return>',lambda:Take_input)

l.pack()
inputtxt.pack()
Display.pack()
Output.pack()
 
mainloop()
```

The two hashed out lines are displaying what I thought was going to solve the problem.  I haven't looked at this in a week and cannot recall the multiple other solutions I attmpeted.

Comment: Why do you combine the list with `", "` and then split by exactly the same string?  `num_list` ends up exactly the same as `numbers`.  Just skip the whole `converted_numbers` thing.  `output = ', '.join(set(numbers))`.  Also, you can say `command=Take_input`.  You don't need a lambda if there are no parameters.

Comment: `inputtxt.delete('1.0','end')`

Comment: Your question is unclear. You know how to clear the output, so why do you need to know how to clear the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I posted a series of half right and half wrong comments.  However, this code works.

I was wrong when I said the return key was `<Enter>`.  Don't take that advice.  ;)  However, you need to bind to the input box, not to the button, which is what you had.

This seems to do what you want.

```
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("300x400")
root.title(" Convert Numbers ")

START = '1.0'

def Take_input(event=None):
    INPUT = inputtxt.get(START,END)

    numbers = INPUT.replace(") ", "").replace("(", "").replace("-", "").split()
    output = ', '.join(set(numbers))    

    Output.delete(START, END)
    Output.insert(END, output)

    root.clipboard_clear()
    root.clipboard_append(output)

    inputtxt.delete(START,END)

l = Label(text = "Paste from FastPeople.com Here:")
l.pack()
     
inputtxt = Text(root, height = 10,
                width = 25,
                bg = "light yellow")

inputtxt.bind('<Return>',Take_input)

inputtxt.pack()
 
Display = Button(root, height = 2,
                 width = 20,
                 text ="Click here to convert.\n Copy from below.",
                 command = Take_input)
Display.pack()
 
Output = Text(root, height = 10,
              width = 25,
              bg = "light cyan")
Output.pack()
 
mainloop()
```

`set`s are not ordered.  If you want the list to be sorted, do

```
    output = ', '.join(sorted(set(numbers)))
```